# if i have go version 1.7 how do i know which minor i am using?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, version-control, format, version

I have no idea about GO, I have never worked with it. But I have helped a team and they need to update their project.

Recently a bug has been found and they have to update the version of go to 1.17.8 but in the go.mod I see that they use 1.17.

if I put 1.17.8 I get a format error because it must be X.X it can't be X.X.X, how do I know which version of minior I'm using? or how can I be sure I'm using the correct version.

```
go 1.17.8  //Compile Error -> go version '1.17.8': must match format 1.23 (I NEED THIS ONE)
go 1.17  //Compile OK
```

Comment: The go directive in the go.mod does **not** select the compiler used; it just states what version the module expects. Just forget about it and update **your installation** of Go. No need to fiddle with the version in go.mod.

Comment: the [go directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) is for compatibility and features required by the module, not to specify patch versions of the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [H]ow can I be sure I'm using the correct version.

By installing the correct version. The go directive in go.mod has no influence on your installation.